# How to pass arguments to other components while we reusing them in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have three components namely, Dashboard,Widget and Workspace Components. I have reused widgets components in the other two. I have to display widgets component with orginal data from DB while reusing it from Dashboard Component, and I need to display dummy data while reusing it from Workspace Component. To achieve the above scenario I have assigned an boolean variable named dummyData and set it to false by default in my WidgetComponent.

```
public dummyData : boolean = false;

ngOnInit(){
  if(!this.dummyData){
    // orginal data
  }else{
    // dummy data
  }
```

Now, I need to pass an boolean argument while reusing this component somewhere else.

How do I pass the argument to the component while reusing it?

Comment: use a shared service

Comment: See https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction. In your case you want widget to remain as dumb a component as possible so I would try to use input unless the situation calls for service.

Comment: Nice discussion of smart vs dumb components, including the trade offs, here... https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the input decorator on the property.

```
@Input()
dummyData = false;
```

and set it true with

```
<widget [dummyData]="true"></widget>
```

Comment: I have did the same but still not working `@Input() dummyData : boolean = false;   <app-widgets [dummyData]="true"></app-widgets>`

Comment: Put a {{ dummyData }} in the template of your widget to see the value.

Comment: Or a console.log(this.dummyData) in your ngOnInit

Comment: I did console.log it just logs the default value false, even though I passed true.

Comment: see this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pd5ow9-so-56520947

Answer (score 0):

you can use Input() directive in your Widget component and pass the state into the component where ever you want to use it.

- Widget component

@Input() stateData: boolean;

- In your selector declaration

refer the component interaction part
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction